# OpenCV solvePnP image points outside of frame

Tags: opencv, pose-estimation

Is there any problem with passing image points to OpenCV's solvePnP function which do not lie inside the image itself? This includes points with negative coordinates.

If have read some tutorials/ answers where it was mentioned implicitely that the point should lie inside the frame but i can't think of any reason why this should be required.

Comment: how do you know the out-of-image points? I think they have to be part of the same pinhole camera model (same calibration etc.) then in theory it could be ok. But not sure about the acutual algorithm.

Comment: i do some geometric calculations, such as fitting lines through detected points and calculating intersection points